# Overwriting a function cause too much recursion

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, overwrite

I wrote this:

```
alert = function(x) {
    alert(x);
};
alert(1);
```

And the firefox's console displayed <kbd>Too much recursion</kbd>

And:

```
var x = alert;
alert = function(y) {
    x(y);
};
alert(1);
```

Works perfectly.

Why the second way works and the first don't?

And `foo=foo;` works.  Isn't `alert=function(x){alert(x);};` the same as `foo=foo;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  When you write:

```
alert=function(x){alert(x);};
```

you're creating a function that, when called, will call itself endlessly until it runs out of stack space. The "alert" symbol you create will become a global variable. Inside the function, *when it is invoked*, the "alert" symbol will be resolved to that global variable.

Because of the semantics of JavaScript, references to variables in functions are resolved afresh on each invocation of the function.  If, after defining that function, you did something like this:

```
var otherAlert = alert;
window.alert = function() { console.log("Hello world"); };
```

then calling "otherAlert" would *not* cause an error, because at that point "alert" would be a different global function.

Comment: Can I overwrite it with a shorter way than creating a variable for that?

Comment: @Mageek well in a broader sense, you cannot really override the "alert()" function successfully.  It has special behavior that you cannot reproduce in plain JavaScript in a browser.

Comment: Okay, but can I write `var x=alert;alert=function(y){x(y);};alert(1);` without using a new variable?

Comment: Did you plan to use the otherAlert variable for anything in your example?

Comment: No you are still changing alert itself.

Comment: @Guffa no I was just re-defining "alert()" and making sure that the other function didn't go away completely.  Note that in the last sentence fragment I mention calling "otherAlert".

Comment: @Mageek basically the answer is no.

Comment: An example of something I could do is `var x=alert;alert=function(y){counter++;x(y);};alert(1);` (Adding a counter).

Comment: Yes you can add a counter, I guess. Be aware that implicit definitions of global variables are not going to be allowed in future versions of JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy You mean that I would have to replace my code by `var x=alert;window.alert=function(y){counter++;x(y);};alert(1);`

Comment: Yes, and also declare `counter` globally: `var counter = 0;` or whatever, and do that outside the function.